# Command `timeout` does not work with Scala - why?

Tags: bash, scala, timeout

**Setup:**
Ubuntu 12.04, 32 Bit; Scala 2.9.1; Java 1.6.0_24

**Description:**

While on the bash command line the command `/usr/bin/timeout 10 scala -version` works fine, it gets stuck when executed within a bash script.

Executing on command line (duration `< 1` seconds):

```
user@ubuntu:~$ /usr/bin/timeout 10 scala -version
Scala code runner version 2.9.1 -- Copyright 2002-2011, LAMP/EPFL
user@ubuntu:~$ echo $?
1
```

The very same command put in a bash script got stuck:

`testScript.sh`:

```
#!/bin/bash
/usr/bin/timeout 10 scala -version
echo "finished with $?"
```

Executing `testScript.sh` (duration 10 seconds):

```
user@ubuntu:~/scripts$ ./testScript.sh
Scala code runner version 2.9.1 -- Copyright 2002-2011, LAMP/EPFL
finished with 124
user@ubuntu:~/scripts$
```

Note: The problem does not appear with Java (which is used by Scala), it seems to be a Scala specific problem.

**Question:** Why does the `timeout` call in the script got stuck ?

How can I fix this / What would be a good workaround ?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Try including the `--foreground` option. From `man timeout`:

> --foreground
>
> > When  not running timeout directly from a shell prompt, allow COMMAND to read from the TTY and receive TTY signals.  In this mode, children of COMMAND will not be timed out.

Using the following test script:

```
#!/bin/bash
/usr/bin/timeout --foreground 10 scala -version
echo "finished with $?"
```

It appears to work fine.

```
$ ./test.sh 
Scala code runner version 2.9.1 -- Copyright 2002-2011, LAMP/EPFL
finished with 1
```

Without `--foreground` the script hangs as you've described.